# Project crashes when initializing variables

Tags: android

My Android activity crashes when I initialize the variables with findViewById

```
public class RaportGreutateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


EditText etDate;
EditText etGreutate;
Button addValues;

DatabaseReference dr;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_raport_greutate);

    init();



}

public void init() {


      etDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDataRaport);
    etGreutate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRaportGreutate);
    addValues = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdaugaraport);
    dr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("raport");

    addValues.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Add();
        }
    });

}
```

This is how my code it looks.

If I comment init(); function from onCreate, my activity opens just fine.

By the way, it's not due to Add(); function, I tried to initialize manually etDate on onCreate method and still the same result so the problem is somewhere on initializing.

Im trying to work with firebase realtime database for the first time.

Thank you!

Edit:

stack trace here

```
01-03 22:21:45.482 12237-12237/com.example.dani.zamfireduard_1076 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                Process: com.example.dani.zamfireduard_1076, PID: 12237
                                                                                java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.dani.zamfireduard_1076/com.example.dani.zamfireduard_1076.RaportGreutateActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                                                                                 Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
                                                                                    at com.example.dani.zamfireduard_1076.RaportGreutateActivity.init(RaportGreutateActivity.java:43)
                                                                                    at com.example.dani.zamfireduard_1076.RaportGreutateActivity.onCreate(RaportGreutateActivity.java:34)
                                                                                    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                                    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
                                                                                    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

XML

```
 <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvData"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:text="@string/Data" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etDataRaport"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/tvData"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/tvData"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/Varsta"
    android:inputType="date" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etRaportGreutate"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/etDataRaport"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/etDataRaport"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnAdaugaraport"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/etRaportGreutate"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tvData"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/tvData"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:text="@string/Greutate" />
```

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: put the activity_raport_greutate xml file

Comment: etRaportGreutate or etDataRaport is a RelativeLayout not the EditText, you missed where to put the @id

Comment: @AakashVerma added

Comment: @diegoveloper added my xml file

Comment: @MarcosVasconcelos I've added xml file where EditText are put. Can you see any mistake there?

Comment: the xml is incomplete, also don't forget to clean and build your project

Comment: @diegoveloper it doesn't let me to add the complete version of xml. But that code shows exactly the variables im trying to initialize in RaportGreutateActivity.

Comment: You are trying to cast a train to an airplane...

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.RelativeLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

This shows you that the problem is you are casting relative layout to edit text .
Check XML of  `etDataRaport` and `etRaportGreutate` .

Comment: I have added xml file with etDataRaport and etRaportGreutate. Do yo see any mistake?

Comment: I don't see any mistake . Did you try to clean the project and rebuild it ?